# How to get dicom files from pacs server to local filesystem with dcm4che 3 c-move command

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

When I use dcm4che3 and dcm4chee2, how to get image data files from one pacs server to my local directory with c-move command?

I use movescu bat file, and when I move from ge pacs to my dcm4chee pacs server,The studyInstanceUID has been changed, and I can't mapping this changed studyuid to the origin ge studyuid.  so I want to get dicom file to my local filesystem directly, Java code will be best.

It seems like ge not support c-get command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the dcm4che tk. In there you will find the binary dcmqr. Here is an example of how to move files from dcm4chee (or any PACS) to your local filesystem.

dcmqr -L LISTENER:11113 PACSAE@PACSIP:PACSPORT -cmove LISTENER -qModalitiesInStudy=CT-cstore CT -cstoredest .

-L is the listener ae title. You will need to specify this in probably 99% of the cases.

-cmove is the command for cmove and again the listener AE.

-qModalitiesInStudy is just one example. Lots of things you can query for but you will need to know the modality for the -cstore option.

-cstoredest is where on your local file system you want to store the files.

Answer (score 0):

We can use dcmqr from dcm4chee2, but in dcm4che3 there is no such command "dcmqr". How I can do this by dcm4che3 ?